# How to split a JSON single column into Pandas DataFrame multiple columns?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, urllib3

I have a JSON file which has all data in one single column. I tried importing using JSON library with URLLIB3, Pandas, and so on, but with some difficulties. I am not sure if the issue is with the file structure, or the way I am handling it. Here is the info I have:

```
<class "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame">
RangeIndex: 362 entries, 0 to 361
Data columns (total 2 columns):

Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype

----------------------------

0   total   362 non-null    int64
1   result  362 non-null    object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 5.8+ KB\`
```

When importing the file with Pandas and printing it, I get this:

```
total                                             result
0      362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY2...
1      362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY2...
2      362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY2...
3      362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY3...
4      362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY5...
..     ...                                                ...
357    362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY1', 'cnpj': '154100...
358    362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY1', 'cnpj': '154100...
359    362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY1', 'cnpj': '154100...
360    362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY4...
361    362  {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY4...
```

When importing with URLLIB3 and JSON library, I get this (truncated for brevity):

```
{'nameRegister': 'COMPANY1', 'cnpj': '12345678901234', 'nameBrand': 'COMPANY1 BRAND', 'email': 'contact@company1.com', 'address': 'Street, Number, Floor, Room, Employees', 'phone': ['(212)1234-5678'], 'site': None, 'st': 'FL', 'city': 'Miami', 'neighborhood': None, 'zip': '30112010', 'dateContract': '30/07/2018', 'partner': 'Mike Jones', 'hub': 'hub1', 'otherPartners': [], 'observation': []}, {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY2', 'cnpj': '12345678901234', 'nameBrand': 'COMPANY2 BRAND', 'email': 'contact@company2.com', 'address': 'Street, Number, Floor, Room, Employees', 'phone': ['(212)1234-5678'], 'site': None, 'st': 'FL', 'city': 'Miami', 'neighborhood': None, 'zip': '30112010', 'dateContract': '30/07/2018', 'partner': 'Mike Jones', 'hub': 'hub2', 'otherPartners': [], 'observation': []}, {'nameRegister': 'COMPANY3', 'cnpj': '12345678901234', 'nameBrand': 'COMPANY3 BRAND', 'email': None, 'address': 'Street, Number, Floor, Room', 'phone': ['12345678'], 'site': None, 'st': 'NY', 'city': 'New York', 'neighborhood': 'Employees', 'zip': '30112010', 'dateContract': None, 'partner': 'Mike Jones', 'hub': 'hub3', 'otherPartners': [], 'observation': []}, {'nameRegister':............
```

**The question is: how do I split "nameRegister", "cnpj", "nameBrand", "email", and so on, each one into individual columns?**

By what I saw, the file does not have a headline. The "total" and "results" were presented by Pandas, but they are not originally in the file.

All data is in the same column now.

Some (from a lot of trials) of the code snippets I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.url.com/file.json"

a = pd.read_json(url)
b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
c = b["result"].apply(lambda s: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(s)))
```

The last line gave this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-963fcad3931e> in <module>
----> 1 c = b["result"].apply(lambda s: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(s)))

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
339     else:
340         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
--> 341             raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
342                             f'not {s.__class__.__name__}')
343         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

```
d = b.drop(columns=["result"])
f = d.join(e)
```

The final result I am seeking is to have a dataframe with each variable ("nameRegister", "cnpj", "nameBrand", "email", and so on), each one into individual columns, so I can export to an Excel file.`

What is wrong and what and how do I need to do?

Comment: Your current `b = ...` line doesn't change anything. `a` is already a DataFrame. You can run normalize on the `result` column directly e.g. `b = pd.json_normalize(a["result"])`

Comment: Thank you @jqurious. How does Pandas will know which separator to use?

On b = ... I used dict to inform it because I saw it was not understanding it was a dictionary.

I already used json-normalize but it did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by separator? `pd.read_json()` parses "text" and returns a DataFrame. In this case, the `result` column contains the dicts you want to normalize. So it's: `pd.json_normalize(pd.read_json(...)["result"])`

Answer (score 1):

Since the json file's schema is unknown, there is no way to guess what's going wrong. Update the question with a sample raw json file from the url where you are fetching it from.

Usually you don't have to do much other than `read_json`.

for example in the below snippet, json is already loaded and dataframe is created with corresponding columns,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("https://api.github.com/users/microsoft/repos")
print(df.id)

Output:
0       6104546
1     104510411
2      58656723
3      13121042
...
28     13141936
29     20027360
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Edit: Updated with OP's json schema.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json("https://sejabtg.com/api/offices.json")   
def parse_registrations(row):
    registration = pd.json_normalize(row.result)
    return registration
        
s = df.apply(parse_registrations, axis=1)
print(type(s))
print(f"df3.0: {s[0].cnpj}")
print(f"df3.1: {s[10].cnpj}")

df = pd.DataFrame()
# iterate over the series and concatenate the dataframes
for i in s:
    df = pd.concat([df, i], axis=0)
print(type(df))
print(df.cnpj)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
df3.0: 0    15673644000118
Name: cnpj, dtype: object
df3.1: 0    15410039000154
Name: cnpj, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
0    15673644000118
0    15673644000118
0    15673644000118
0    24151517000140
0    18146649000180
          ...      
0    15410039000154
0    15410039000154
0    15410039000154
0    17263248000148
0    17263248000148
Name: cnpj, Length: 362, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you @Jimson-James for your comments. Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but the raw json file would be this one: https://sejabtg.com/api/offices.json

This is what you mean?

I tried posting all the information I understood would draw the picture I have here. Please, let me know if you need something else.

Thanks for your help!

Btw: I tried tagging you with @ but could not find you. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The data you need is in the result. You can access it using ‘df[‘result’].values’

Comment: `json_normalize` and `df['result'].values` is the key point!